# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

I am working on microservices and I am trying to migrate all my configuration to centralized config. However I am not sure but there is something wrong with encoding, decrypting or parsing password to Spring Cloud Eureka (or is the url ok and it secured properly cause there is password?). This is what I an getting when running `docker-compose up` . These exceptions are thrown for each of microservices.

```
movie_1            | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://u:${app.eureka-password}@eureka:8761/eureka/
movie_1            |    at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:906) ~[na:na]
movie_1            |    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.resource(Client.java:434) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:187) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:165) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1051) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:965) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1479) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1446) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
movie_1            |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
movie_1            |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
movie_1            |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
movie_1            |    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
movie_1            | Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://u:${app.eureka-password}@eureka:8761/eureka/
movie_1            |    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2936) ~[na:na]
movie_1            |    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3270) ~[na:na]
movie_1            |    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3181) ~[na:na]
movie_1            |    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3137) ~[na:na]
movie_1            |    at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:623) ~[na:na]
movie_1            |    at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:904) ~[na:na]
movie_1            |    ... 25 common frames omitted
movie_1            | 
movie_1            | 2020-03-25 04:41:03.276  WARN 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://u:${app.eureka-password}@eureka:8761/eureka/
movie_1            | 2020-03-25 04:41:03.276 ERROR 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MOVIE/ef7c617370f2:movie:8080 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server
movie_1            | 
movie_1            | com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1051) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:965) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1479) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1446) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
movie_1            |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
movie_1            |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
movie_1            |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
movie_1            |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
movie_1            |    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
movie_1
```

This is how my global configuration file looks like:
What is more (due to the course from which this code is) these encrypted values should be like:

```
app.eureka-password: p 
spring.rabbitmq,password: quest
```

All of these code is working find on old build where there is no centralized configuration and code is nor encrypted. `

**application.yml**

```
app:
  eureka-username: u
  eureka-password: '{cipher}bf298f6d5f878b342f9e44bec08cb9ac00b4ce57e98316f030194a225fac89fb'
  eureka-server: localhost
  auth-server: localhost

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: "http://${app.eureka-username}:${app.eureka-password}@${app.eureka-server}:8761/eureka/"
    initialInstanceInfoReplicationIntervalSeconds: 5
    registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 5
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 5
    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 5

spring.rabbitmq:
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 5672
  username: guest
  password: '{cipher}17fcf0ae5b8c5cf87de6875b699be4a1746dd493a99d926c7a26a68c422117ef'

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder:
  brokers: 127.0.0.1
  defaultBrokerPort: 9092

# WARNING: Exposing all management endpoints over http should only be used during development, must be locked down in production!
management.endpoint.health.show-details: "ALWAYS"
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: "*"

---
spring.profiles: docker

spring.rabbitmq.host: rabbitmq

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers: kafka

app:
  eureka-server: eureka
  auth-server: auth-server
```

When i replace this encrypted data and build project again I got something like:

```
ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN
```

Please let me know if you need more information or code. Any ideas, help will be appreciated.

If it goes about eureka server there are couple lines of code only:

**Main class:**

```
@Slf4j
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class EurekaServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Security config:**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final String username;
    private final String password;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(
        @Value("${app.eureka-username}") String username,
        @Value("${app.eureka-password}") String password
    ) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
                .withUser(username).password(password)
                .authorities("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

**and bootstrap.yml:**

```
app.config-server: localhost

spring:
  application.name: eureka-server
  cloud.config:
    failFast: true
    retry:
      initialInterval: 3000
      multiplier: 1.3
      maxInterval: 10000
      maxAttempts: 20
    uri: http://${CONFIG_SERVER_USR}:${CONFIG_SERVER_PWD}@${app.config-server}:8888

---
spring.profiles: docker

app.config-server: config-server
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas guys?

Comment: If the details you posted are all actual copy pasted values, I notice that your global configuration has a rogue comma instead of full stop in spring.rabbitmq,password - not sure if it is related but may be causing problems dealing with that whole file?